# Is storage being passed to this newly created contract?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, storage

I'm looking at uniswapv3 code and noticed something peculiar. When uniswap creates a pool, it lays out parameters in storage and then immediately deletes them after the contract is created. Is this newly created contract inheriting the creating contracts storage? Where can I read more about this?

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/f03155670ec1667406b83a539e23dcccf32a03bc/contracts/UniswapV3PoolDeployer.sol#L34-L36

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/f03155670ec1667406b83a539e23dcccf32a03bc/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol#L44-L53